# Is it possible change some text along with some number...inside or outside the textbox onchange dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox which displays area(of square) in different units onchange dropdown...I was trying to display the units(like 54 sqm or 45 sqfeet) along with the value of area inside the text box......
or the units outside the textbox....
Please help.

```
<body>
    <form>
        Select unit:
        <select id="myList" onchange="myFunction(this.value);prop(this.value)">
            <option>
            </option>
            <option value="1">
                meter 
            </option>
            <option value="3.29">
                Feet
            </option>
            <option value="4">
                Inches
            </option>
            <option value="7">
                centimeter
            </option>
            <option value="2">
                meter
            </option>
        </select>
        </br>
        select decimal points:
        <select id="g" onchange="myFunction('myList',this.id);prop('myList',this.id)"
        ;>
            <option value="0">
            </option>
            <option value="1">
                1
            </option>
            <option value="2">
                2
            </option>
            <option value="3">
                3
            </option>
            <option value="4">
                4
            </option>
            <option value="5">
                5
            </option>
            <option value="6">
                6
            </option>
        </select>
        <p> diameter:
            <input type="text" id="txtdia" onchange="myFunction();prop()" ;/>
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
            Your new diameter is:
            <input type="text" id="favorite" size="20" onchange="myFunction()">
        </p>
        <p>
            Your Circumference is:
            <input type="text" id="circum" size="20" />
            <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="prop()" />
        </p>
    </form>


<script>
function myFunction() {
var mylist = document.getElementById("myList");
//var dia=null;
var dia = document.getElementById("txtdia").value;
var g = document.getElementById("g");
var g = g.options[g.selectedIndex].value;
var newdia = dia / myList.options[myList.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById("favorite").value = newdia.toPrecision(g);}

 function prop() {
var dia = document.getElementById("txtdia").value;
var myList = document.getElementById("myList");
var g = document.getElementById("g");
var g = g.options[g.selectedIndex].value;
var circumf = dia * 3.14 / myList.options[myList.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById("circum").value = circumf.toPrecision(g);}
    </script>
```

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Comment: That seems super easy, but post some code so we can help in a more throughout way

Comment: @cr0ss,@j08691..here is the code...the textbox shows calculated diameter and circumference onchange the units and decimal points from drop down...But I want to show...the units as well with the calculated value.

Comment: Your form doesn't make too much sense. What values are you associating with the units? Are you trying to convert from one unit to another?

Comment: Also, for future editors, here's a base **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YcXLX/)** you can use with the code OP posted.

Comment: @LaughDonor..yes..but not like a calculator which just converts one unit to another...I should be able to choose whatever units I wish...and along with the value I get in the textbox I need text of the converted unit...like 45 meter or 45 inches

Comment: @LaughDonor:Thanks for that suggestion...I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `prop()` function, the last line, change it to:

```
document.getElementById("circum").value = circumf.toPrecision(g) + " " + myList.options[myList.selectedIndex].text;
```

Inside your `myFunction()` function, the last line, change it to:

```
document.getElementById("favorite").value = newdia.toPrecision(g) + " " + myList.options[myList.selectedIndex].text;
```

Maybe that's what you're looking for? It basically just adds a space and the text value of the selected dropdown option to your text field

Comment: @LaughDonor...Thanks a loads it worked...